# attempted import in typescript is failing

Tags: angular, typescript, import, importerror

I have this typescript file called backendUrls.ts:

```
 // root url
  export const rooturl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';

//get a list of all cities
  export const cityListUrl = rooturl + '/city-list';

  // get all form choice perams
  export const venueFilterOptionsUrl = rooturl + '/venue-filter-options-list/'; /** plus a user entered city*/

  export const neighborhoodGetUrl = rooturl +'neighborhood-list';
```

its a really cool file

I am trying to import it into this file:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import{Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import {venueFilterOptionsUrl, neighborhoodGetUrl} from './services/backendUrls';
@Injectable()
export class DynamicFormDataService{......
```

it too is a really cool file

they are in this structure

```
`app
   services
      backendurls.ts
      dynamicFormDataService.ts`
```

in case you missed it I am trying to import the `backendUrls.ts` file like this:

```
import {venueFilterOptionsUrl, neighborhoodGetUrl} from './services/backendUrls';
```

but bro I tell you it aint happening and its driving me nuts what I am I doing wrong, I feel like Im following the awesomely cool [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) pretty well

Stuffs lame man

Comment: why `'./services/backendUrls'` when they are in the same directory? have you tried `'./backendurls' `?

Comment: hmmm.... damn it that worked lol Thanks Avril, was never into your music but I am into your stack overflow answers!